# Как вывести количество записей за день, неделю, месяц, год. Начиная с этого д/н/м/г

Tags: php, mysql, графики

Есть таблица:

| id | name | date(y-m-d) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nam1 | 2022-03-13 |
| 2 | nam2 | 2022-03-14 |
| 3 | nam3 | 2022-03-15 |
| 4 | nam4 | 2022-04-02 |
| 5 | nam5 | 2022-05-14 |
| 6 | nam6 | 2022-05-14 |
| 7 | nam7 | 2022-05-18 |
| 8 | nam8 | 2022-06-20 |
| 9 | nam9 | 2022-06-01 |
| 10 | nam10 | 2022-06-29 |
| 11 | nam11 | 2022-06-17 |

Таблица простая. Даже с дополнительными данными она будет простой.
Я могу выводить например значения по месяцам вот так:
**PDO**

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT month(names.date) as date, count(id) as c_name FROM names GROUP BY month(names.date) LIMIT 30");
```

По неделям:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT week(names.date) as date, count(id) as c_name FROM names GROUP BY week(names.date) LIMIT 30");
```

Все у меня получается.
Но у меня 2 проблемы:

1. даты месяца не выводиться полной а только число месяца. (Выводиться 6, а нужно 2022-06 что бы знать год)
2. мне нужно вывести целых 30 результатов. Где нет записей по дате оставлять 0.

Выводиться сейчас вот так (по месяцам):

**"date":"3","c_name":"3"

"date":"4","c_name":"1"

"date":"5","c_name":"3"

"date":"6","c_name":"4"**

Нужно (так-же по месяцам 30 раз начиная с этого месяца/года/недели/дня)

30
..
"date":"2020-6","c_name":"0"
"date":"2020-7","c_name":"0"
"date":"2020-8","c_name":"0"
"date":"2020-9","c_name":"0"
"date":"2020-10","c_name":"0"
"date":"2020-11","c_name":"0"
"date":"2020-12","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-1","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-2","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-3","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-4","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-5","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-6","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-7","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-8","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-9","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-10","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-11","c_name":"0"
"date":"2021-12","c_name":"0"
"date":"2022-1","c_name":"0"
"date":"2022-2","c_name":"0"
"date":"2022-3","c_name":"3"
"date":"2022-4","c_name":"1"
"date":"2022-5","c_name":"3"
**"date":"2022-6","c_name":"4"** -> начиная с текущего месяца

Да, возможно задача сложная. Я ни как не могу построить такой график. Тем более что я не могу вывести и год с месяцем вместе.
Прошу пожалуйста, помогите с этой задачей, вывести такой график, желательно только по месяцам, а дальше со днями, годами, неделями я сам.

Comment: на первый вопрос - в лоб как-то так `SELECT concat(year(names.date), ,'-', month(names.date))`

Comment: а вот заполнить пропущенные даты - делайте временную таблицу

Comment: @splash58 спасибо за ответ! Буду пробовать.
Временная таблица, там где будут у меня даты?

Comment: Да, со списком всех дат месяца. и join'ом их заполнять

Answer (score 1):

По ощущениям, у вас запросы должны отрабатывать неправильно, т.к. вы сами говорите, что у вас в результате только одно число, т.е. группировка по месяцу, допустим `6` будет за все года, которые имеются в таблице, хотя, возможно это то поведение, которое вы хотите получить.

У вас два готовых запроса, однако, вы зачем-то еще используете такую конструкцию: `month(names.date)` и в `select` и в `group by`.

Не знаю, что у вас за СУРБД, в таком случае, проверьте сначала это:

```
            SELECT
                -- изменяем формат даты к: `2022-06`
                DATE_FORMAT(names.date, '%Y-%m') as year_and_month, 
                count(id) as c_name
            FROM names
            GROUP BY year_and_month 
            LIMIT 30
```

Если отработает, будете иметь в результате дату сразу с годом + месяцем (если вдруг Postgres, то почитайте о `date_trunc('month', names.date)`, должно отработать).

По неделям немного интересней, придется заюзать конкатенацию:

```
            SELECT
                -- изменяем формат даты к: `2022-06`, но заместо месяца уже будет номер недели
                CONCAT(YEAR(names.date), '-', WEEK(names.date)) as year_and_week,
                count(id) as c_name
            FROM names
            GROUP BY year_and_week 
            LIMIT 30
```

Comment: спасибо! Вы мне помогли сделать более лучше результат. 
Все таки, да, вы правы. У меня будут количество записей по всем месяцам не зависимо от года. Я даже не заметил. Спасибо! На счет использование `month` в `select`   и `group by` - так-же спасибо. Не знал. На счет недель так-же спасибо, буду пробовать,  но мало что там понял. Но понимаю то что, все таки мне придется делать реализацию двух запросов, со днями, месяцами, годами - однотипно, а с недели по сложнее. Если что спасибо вам!